# Delete data from a MSSQL standby database?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to delete data from a read only standby database that imports shipped log files?

At least in my theory this shouldn't be possible because the deletion would change the LSN and the log shipping should break.

What I need is a smaller sized database than the database that ships the logs. So basically I need a way to have the (readonly) standby server storing only the most recent data. Any ideas or recommendations on this?

Comment: Integration services might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to delete data from a read only standby database that
>   imports shipped log files?

No, this is not possible.

With SQL Replication you can publish the tables in the database and apply a filter so you would only replicate the data that matches the filter, but this can not be accomplished with a log-shipped database.